# Should a bean parameter be defined in the same class as another bean?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I’m looking at [an example I found](https://reflectoring.io/spring-boot-testconfiguration/) for SpringBootTestConfiguration.
My question here is -
I have seen examples of inter reference beans where we usually define a bean of the dependent class and pass that as a parameter.  Similarly,  do we need to declare a bean for WebClient.Builder? If not how does this piece of code work?

As per my understanding we should create a bean for WebClient.Builder before this should be passed as a parameter for WebClient bean definition.